# What do I call the collection of different versions of a file?

Tags: single-word-requests

At work, we have all the versions of reports we are working on in individual folders. Eg. all 8 drafts of our last report were put in the same folder along with the final version.

How do I explain it in this way: "Each folder holds a _______"

I've thought of "repository", but the folder itself is a repository.

This is similar to how Gmail calls collections of emails a "conversation".

Comment: `edition` maybe?

Comment: @Sprottenwels I can see each draft being an edition, but what would I call all the editions as a whole?

Comment: I could think of a phase, a chapter or an episode. But it exceeds my skills to give a definitive answer

Comment: I think it is better to be clear, even if it takes a few more words. Such as '... holds the final report and the preceeding drafts'. You could use a term such as revision history or version management, but thats a bit confusing, as sometimes that is controoled by software, but here you are doing it in a manual way.

Comment: `history` might work.  Each folder holds a history of the report.  Perhaps `evolution`, and each folder holds the evolution of the report.  I'm coming at this from a software engineering perspective, so a repository holds versions of files, and older ones are either commits, or revision history.

Comment: Generally the term is defined by the purveyors of the technology being used.  But "chronological record" or some such might be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two terms applicable

- version chain
- version stack

Thus you would say, a file version-chain, or a file version-stack.

They are not the same , but has the same results. In either case, you get to access any version of a file within its chain, or its stack.

Version-chaining is used by cyber-file version management software, to avoid recreating a whole file for each version.

A version-chain comprises a full-base version, followed by a chain of cumulative subsequent changes. Each version of a file is actually only the difference vectors compared to the previous version. A version chain is the flux of chains of change-vectors of a file. Each *version* is a cross-section of that flux at one of the discrete stages of change.

Looking at a file thro its version-chain perspective, allows us to understand the term *change-history* of a file.

A version-stack of a file, is the human perspective a file and its stack of versions. When we look at a version in a stack of versions of a file, we see each version as complete documents on human-abstract perspective. We don't care if each version is due to wholly replicating from the previous version with changes, or just a cross-section of change-vector flow in the chain of changes.

Therefore, as a usual and normal human, one would like to look at a file as a version-stack. Whereas programmers dealing with managing the changes would look at a file thro the perspective of its version-chain.

Also, since you are dealing with *papered / paperized* versions, it would naturally be *version-stack*.

Comment: I think you're on the right track here. But if the audience is non-technical, *version history* might be the better choice.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

> Each file is a **snapshot** of the project.

But that implies progress over time. It sounds like you have different versions created by different collaborators.

Since you thought of *repository* , you could use **fork** or **branch**. However that's rather specific. I probably wouldn't use those words outside of anything related to git.

Answer (score 0):

How about ***[archive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/archive)***?

> ***Archive:*** The place where historical documents or records are kept.

(OED)

***Each folder holds an archive of all previous file versions.***

Comment: Archive tends to imply something written a while ago, but I think we are referring to recent documents here.